# last_insert_id dosent work hibernate informix

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, informix, spring-rest

i have this problem, use hibernate + informix i execute query with .executeUpdate(), after i need to get the last id inserted.

the sentence that I am executing was built dynamically but syntactically it is correct since when reviewing the table where it should generate the record, it inserts it correctly.

code:

```
Transaction txInternal = session.beginTransaction();
SQLQuery qExecute = session.createSQLQuery(query);
int temp = qExecute.executeUpdate();
txInternal.commit();

if(statement.toLowerCase().contains("insert")){
   BigInteger qLastId = (BigInteger) session.createQuery("SELECT last_insert_id() as lastId").uniqueResult();
   //BigInteger qLastId = (BigInteger) session.createQuery("SELECT DBINFO( 'sqlca.sqlerrd1' ) FROM tb_user").uniqueResult();
    int lastId = qLastId.intValue();

    error.put("lastId", lastId);
    ids.add(lastId);
}else{
    ids.add(0);
    error.put("lastId", 0);
 }
```

hibernate properties:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.charset=utf8
hibernate.charEncoding=utf8
hibernate.unicode=true
```

error:

```
    Información:   insert into tb_test_template values(0, 'origne', 'origne editado', '1', '10', '1110')
Información:   Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        tb_test_template

    values
        (0, 'origne', 'origne editado', '1', '10', '1110')
Información:   resultado de la insercion: 1
ERROR:   <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
ERROR:   <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
<AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3527)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:706)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:562)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)
    at hscorp.oax.dao.FileDAOImpl.testInsert(FileDAOImpl.java:1052)
    at hscorp.oax.controller.InitController.saveRecordTemplate(InitController.java:377)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:198)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Grave:   No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'last_insert_id' {originalText=last_insert_id}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
```

Comment: Unless you know something I don't, `last_insert_id()` isn't a function in Informix.  Do you know the type of the serial column — is it SERIAL,  or SERIAL8, or BIGSERIAL?  Or is the number generated via a SEQUENCE?  There are different ways of getting at those values. (You can actually have both a SERIAL and either SERIAL8 or BIGSERIAL (but not bot) column on a table, and each gets its own ID — but it's pretty pointless to do so).  It would be worth mentioning which version of Informix you're using and the platform you're using it on; it sometimes matters, though it probably doesn't here.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how your code is accessing Informix; I don't see the Informix JDBC driver functions in the stack traceback.  I'm not a Java expert (I spell it "coffee").  And I don't know the JDBC equivalent of ESQL/C's `sqlca` (SQL Communications Area), which is one of the places where some of the information is stored.  In C code, `ifx_getserial8()` and `ifx_getbigserial()` get those values.  I don't know the equivalent with Informix JDBC (but I'm not clear whether Informix JDBC is in use, either).